# 'ascii' error at /@@mail-controlpanel

Tags: plone

I have a 'ascii' error at /@@mail-controlpanel. How can i check the values and fix that?
The site is running Plone4.2 on Debian6.

Regards

my Traceback:

```
...
Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: /home/plone42/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.controlpanel-2.2.5-py2.7.egg/plone/app/controlpanel/control-panel.pt
   - Line 110, Column 28
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'widget'>
   - Names:
  {'args': (),
   'container': <PloneSite at /intranetcfa>,
   'context': <PloneSite at /intranetcfa>,
   'default': <object object at 0x7f11f8d43b40>,
   'here': <PloneSite at /intranetcfa>,
   'loop': {},
   'nothing': None,
   'options': {},
   'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x5e37e10>,
   'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://91.121.151.215:8088/intranetcfa/@@mail-controlpanel>,
   'root': <Application at >,
   'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x4edd790>,
   'traverse_subpath': [],
   'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>,
   'view': <Products.Five.metaclass.MailControlPanel object at 0x7f11ea4efbd0>,
   'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x7f11ea506110>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 155, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 117, in render
  Module zope.formlib.textwidgets, line 134, in __call__
  Module zope.formlib.widget, line 627, in renderElement
  Module zope.formlib.widget, line 612, in renderTag
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Obviously there is somewhere a mismatch between ISO-8859-15 and UTF-8 and unicode...only the debugger can help you here...

Comment: The error probably come from the values in  Site 'From' name or Site 'From' address. Can i change these values without access to @@mail-controlpanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to change the from name/address directly through the ZMI under

```
http://host:port/your_plone/manage_propertiesForm
```

by adjusting the email_from_address or email_from_name properties.

Comment: Thanksyou very much for your help. The problem was an accented character in 'email_from_name'. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Feel free to file a Plone bugreport....this error should not happen and the bug should be fixed somehow.

Comment: I just fill a bug report. Thanks again.